# How to add new details to dictionary with user input through CMD

Tags: python

I am new to Python programming and I created a method to accept a new student name and new grade into an existing dictionary through user input from cmd, but I am finding it difficult to sort. How do I sort that out?

I have been able to code the other methods properly. Only the above method is giving errors at run-time:

```
StudDict={'James':[70,75,95,],

      'Adams':[75,90,73],

      'Benjamin':[80,79,85]}

#The below is where im having problems.

def AddStudent(): #This method adds new student and grade to the existing Student dictionarydictionary

    StudToAdd= input('ENTER STUDENT NAME TO BE ADDED:  ')

    GradesToAdd=input("ENTER NEW STUDENT'S GRADE:  ")

    StudDict[StudToAdd].append(GradesToAdd)

    print(StudDict)
```

I expect to be able to add new students(keys),and grades(values) to the existing student dictionary which I have already created and find the new added details in the dictionary.

Comment: look at this could be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key

Comment: please try to set data to dictionary by this way StudDict[StudToAdd] = GradesToAdd

Comment: it's best to follow PEP 8 naming conventions, for functions+variables use lowercase and separated by underscores if necessary - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names

Comment: Thanks everyone,all your suggestions worked,i appreciate this community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your code didn't work is because your new student dictionary isn't defined as a list; therefore, you can't append.

There are couple ways of doing this but keeping it the same logic as you have now, you'll need to add a few extra steps.

```
>>> students = {'James': [70, 75, 95], 'Adams': [75, 90, 73], 'Benjamin': [80, 79, 85]}
>>> def add_student ():
...     new_student = input ('Enter student name to be added:' )
...     grades = input ('Enter new student\'s grade: ')
...     grades = grades.split (',')  # Split grades by comma
...     grades = [int (grade.strip (' ')) for grade in grades]  # Strip space between each grade & convert to integers
...     students [new_student] = grades  # Assign new student with grades
... 
>>> add_student()
Enter student name to be added:>? John
Enter new student's grade: >? 82, 79, 77
>>> students
{'Benjamin': [80, 79, 85], 'Adams': [75, 90, 73], 'James': [70, 75, 95], 'John': [82, 79, 77]}
```

**Updating answer based on comments**
To remove the students score, you'll need ensure that the name as well as the score exists in database.

```
>>> def remove_scores():
...     name = input('Enter student name whose scores would be removed: ')
...     score = int (input('Enter score to be removed: '))
...     # Checking both student name and score exists in database
...     if name in students and score in students [name]:
...         score_index = students [name].index (score)  # Obtain the index location of the score
...         del students [name][score_index]
...         print (students)
...     else:
...         print('Student %s and/or %s score is not in our database.' % (name, score))
...
```

First, let's add one extra score '79' to Adams to be deleted.

```
>>> students ['Adams'].append (79)
>>> students
{'Benjamin': [80, 79, 85], 'Adams': [75, 90, 73, 79], 'James': [70, 75, 97]}
```

Next, test the name and score condition.

```
>>> remove_scores()
Enter student name whose scores would be removed: >? Larry
Enter score to be removed: >? 59
Student Larry and/or 59 score is not in our database.
>>> remove_scores()
Enter student name whose scores would be removed: >? Adams
Enter score to be removed: >? 77
Student Adams and/or 77 score is not in our database.
```

Once we're happy with the result, let's delete and see the results.

```
>>> remove_scores()
Enter student name whose scores would be removed: >? Adams
Enter score to be removed: >? 79
{'Benjamin': [80, 79, 85], 'Adams': [75, 90, 73], 'James': [70, 75, 97]}
```

Comment: ENTER LOGIN:  Admin1

ENTER PASSWORD:  Pass123@

welcome ****Admin1****


    ****************WELCOME TO STUDENT GRADING SYSTEM****************

    [.] - PRINT STUDENT DICTIONARY
    [0] - ADD NEW STUDENT(S)
    [1] - ENTER GRADES
    [2] - REMOVE STUDENT
    [3] - STUDENT AVERAGE GRADES
    [4] - EXIT PROGRAM


~~~~~~WHAT WOULD YOU LIKE TO DO(ENTER A NUMBER)~~~~~~:  0

ENTER STUDENT NAME TO BE ADDED:  Dreamzboy

ENTER NEW STUDENT'S GRADE:  99,99,99

{'James': [70, 75, 95], 'Adams': [75, 90, 73], 'Benjamin': [80, 79, 85], 'Dreamzboy': 

[99, 99, 99]}

Comment: Still on the same program,im trying to code a method that can remove scores one after the other.can you help with that too.Here is what i coded.

def remove_scores():

    StudNaMe=input("ENTER STUDENT'S NAME WHOSE SCORE(S) WOULD BE 

REMOVED:  ")

    Score_remove=print("ENTER SCORE TO BE REMOVED:   ")

    if StudNaMe in StuDict:

        StuDict[StudNaMe].remove(Score_remove)

        print(StuDict)

    else:

        print(StudNaMe,"IS NOT IN OUR DATABASE ")

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `defaultdict`, as it seems perfect for what you are trying to do:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

StudDict = defaultdict(list)
# Optionally, provide existing data to the object:
# StudDict = defaultdict(list, {existing_dict_with_data})

def add_student():
    ...
    StudDict[StudToAdd].append(GradesToAdd)
```

See documentation for more details here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: You're welcome! Consider marking the issue as solved :)